# Are there any complete data sets to test a POSIX regular expressions engine?

Tags: regex, testing, posix

I've implemented some regular expressions engines and now I need to test them, so I'm looking for a complete data set to test with. By data set, I mean a list of patterns with a list of strings. Is there something similar or the best way is to create data by myself?

Upd: i'm looking for POSIX regexes

Comment: I hardly think some random strings would be useful for you. You have to write some strings based on your regex engine and see the result.

Comment: @Shafizadeh yep, agree, but I thought there is a common way of testing regex engines... i don't know,that's why i ask)

Comment: There are multiple flavors of regular expressions. POSIX and [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) being the two big ones. Which one are you asking for?

Comment: @Schwern sorry, forgot to mention, POSIX

Comment: @Polina Too bad, [PCRE has a nice suite of test data](http://vcs.pcre.org/pcre2/code/trunk/testdata/). You might try the [Open POSIX Test Suite](http://posixtest.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Schwern anyway thank u very much, now I know what exactly i need)

Comment: @Polina: too bad - it's an interesting assignment, but such recommendations are [off topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). (I'd take Schwern's advice.)